# HTML page redirecting using META refresh not working

Tags: internet-explorer, meta-tags

I am using IE 11.
I have index.html that used to redirect to Home.jsp page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
   <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/da8/jsp/Home.jsp"></HEAD>
   <BODY>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=/da8/jsp/Home.jsp">

<body onload="window.open('/da8/jsp/Home.jsp');">

<body onload="window.location.href('/da8/jsp/Home.jsp');">
```

But nothing works.

I also checked the META Refresh settings in my IE and it is set to true.
[image: META REFRESH]

Does anyone know what could be this due to?

Answer (score 0):

I had to forget about redirecting using `META REFRESH` in `index.html`.

Instead, the only way I was able to redirect to `Home.jsp` was using:

```
Redirect /index.html /da8/jsp/Home.jsp
```

in Apache configuration file: `httpd.conf`